# SQL query to return branch status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to get Branch that has no roles that is ( Doctor, Engineer, Admin) showing an extra column of role status as "NO", where the branch that has any of the roles that are ( Doctor, Engineer, Admin) to show as Yes in "Role Status" column. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I'm using MS SQL.

In the below example as Scotland has a Nurse who doesn't belong to the roles of ( Doctor, Engineer, Admin) are showing as "No"

[image: Table_name]

Comment: **Expression** @Squirrel . T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) Statements, which can return boolean results or control the logical flow operation of code, only [`CASE` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which return a scalar value.

Comment: I can understand but I have 172 branches, need some other options. If there were 3 branches then i can use case when branch = 'Kent' and role in ( Doctor,ENgineer,Admin) then 'Yes' else 'no' end as 'Role Status' but i have 172 branch and don't want to do the same for all 172. must be an easier way

Comment: @Squirrel its MS sql as i have mentioned. It support Case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a separate table for branches -- which seems like a reasonable assumption -- you can use `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from branches b
where not exists (select 1
                  from yourtable t
                  where role in ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin')
                 );
```

If you want a column appended onto your existing table, then use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(role in ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by branch) > 0
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as rolestatus
from yourtable t;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using case when expression

```
   select branch
   , role
   ,  case when role NOT IN  ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin') THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END status 
  from my_table
```

Comment: As far as I understood the OP this won't help: I guess it should be "Yes" if a branch features any of the roles... so e.g. if in above mentioned example Scotland hat a second row with "Engineer" both rows of Scotland should be "Yes"...

Answer (score 1):

use analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select t.*,
       case when count(case when role in ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin') then 1 end) 
                       over (partition by branch) > 0
            then 'YES' 
            else 'NO' 
       end as status 
from your_Table t
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using the `CHOOSE` function

```
drop table if exists #temp;
go
create table #temp(
  branch      varchar(10) not null,
  [role]      varchar(20) not null);

insert into #temp values
('Kent', 'Doctor'),
('Kent', 'Admin'),
('Scotland', 'Nurse');


select branch, choose(max(v.cnt) 
                      over (partition by branch)+1,
                      'No', 'Yes') role_status
from #temp
     cross apply (values (iif([role] in 
                        ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin'), 1, 0)))
                        v(cnt);
```

```
branch      role_status
Kent        Yes
Kent        Yes
Scotland    No
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a subquery or a cte in order to evaluate if any of the roles is present in the branch at hand:

```
WITH cteRole AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT Branch
    FROM [table]
    WHERE [Role] IN ('Doctor', 'Engineer', 'Admin')
)
SELECT t.Branch, t.[Role], CASE WHEN lkp.Branch IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [Role Status]
  FROM [Table] t
  LEFT JOIN cteRole lkp ON lkp.Branch = t.Branch
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i will give it a go now and let you know.